# Rails:sorting from controller doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to sort array from controller, that doesn't works, but throws no errors.

```
def my_published
  @tests=Test.where(:user_id => current_user.id, :state=>'saved')
  @tests=@tests.sort { |p1, p2| p1.rating <=> p2.rating }
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js{@tests}
  end
end
```

Rating is an integer.
P.S. To display array I use each method.

Comment: Try putting @tests.sort!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this construction:

```
@test = Test.where(:user_id=>current_user.id, :state=>'saved').order('rating')
```

You can add the direction of order:

```
order('rating DESC') or order('rating ASC')
```

Comment: I still want to know why the other sorting method wasn't working!

Comment: I suppose because <=> operator is for sorting strings.

Comment: Nope, it can sort integers as well.